# redirect to localhost/magento2 after change folder name

Tags: magento2, url

I change `magento2` folder name to `magento2-me`, but when i open `localhost/magento2-me`, it redirect to `localhost/magento2/index.php/?SID=qfj3f4tkjlpukb9se92434dvt3` **404 page**.

How i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change inside database table **core_config_data**.

find path field with name like, `web/unsecure/base_url` and replace those value field with **`localhost/magento2/`** to **`localhost/magento2-me/`**

Clear cache and remove root var  folder.